# Error in programming ESP32-S2-WROVER

Tags: programming, esp32, programmer

I have two circuits. One with **ESP32-WROVER-IB** and another with **ESP32-S2-WROVER**. I connected both similar fashions.

However, I see I can flash the **ESP32-WROVER-IB**, but I am unable to flash the **ESP32-S2-WROVER**. The circuits are given below.

[image: ESP32-WROVER-IB: I can program this module]

[image: ESP32-S2-WROVER: I cannot program this module]

Also, I notice that when I press reset button on **ESP32-WROVER-IB**, I get the following message but I get nothing with **ESP32-S2-WROVER**.

```
rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x17 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0030,len:1420
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40078000,len:13540
load:0x40080400,len:3604
entry 0x400805f0
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
```

I want to know what am I missing to flash the **ESP32-S2-WROVER** in the traditional way of using a TTL to USB converter.

Comment: are you certain that pullup resistors are required for both modules?

Comment: @jsotola, I also tried without pull-up resistances, but it didn't work.

Comment: what about pull-down? ... did you read the ESP32-S2-WROVER datasheet?

Comment: @jsotola, The circuit is correct. I had problem with the connections (I mean the wire was broken and I didn't notice it until later). Pull up resistance was absolutely required for the EN pin.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit is working. I have some bad circuit. I fixed the connection error, and it is working as expected. I am sorry to waste your time.

Comment: If by "fixed connection error" you mean "added ground wire", then you indeed fixed it. If not, then you should expect more errors in the future.